# Root Animation unusual position and non root animation snaps back

Tags: animation, unreal-4, blueprints

Im trying to do a stop animation . when i release the W key then from Run it will do this animation then goto IDLE . But somehow this is not working right. as you see in those videos below. So how do i achieve this ?

Im using animation from mixamo.

After Root Motion [http://i.imgur.com/JwY98P2.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/JwY98P2.gifv)

Before Root Motion  https://fat.gfycat.com/ReflectingMealyCrane.mp4

Comment: Bottom link is broken - notice that it is https, and you are probably logged in whereas we are not.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer its fixed . the animations did not have root bone as needed in unreal . so i added a root bone in blender and imported it.

Comment: Good. You should write an answer and accept it, then.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer added answer and also updated the bottom link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixamo has root bone as hip bones. So i needed to add a Root bone as parent of all bones using blender. 
This video shows it . https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a79tRO7M0I .

Some other videos also fixes this issue but they were too complicated, as im not an animator i just tried this one and it worked so far so good.

Comment: also note: some animations dont work need lots of rearrangements of keyframes to make it work.  not worth it